# Handle number of rows in GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a need to create a GridView, that will have only 1 row and many columns.

Because i want to realize SemanticZoom and Scroll into view.

GridView is populated by CustomUserControls here is my code:

```
<SemanticZoom IsZoomOutButtonEnabled="False">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView x:Name="ZoomedInView" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionMode="None" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle}">
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
                <Controls:FirstControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <Controls:SecondControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <Controls:ThirdControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView SelectionMode="None" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```

The controls Width will be handled by its children, but height must be full size of GridView, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the

ItemsPanel to:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Worked like a charm